# How can i run a function based on the status code on a flask app

Tags: python, flask

I have been messing around with flask on my raspberry pi and i've noticed every time i open the webpage i have as a template on it there are a bunch of status codes displayed (mostly 200 thankfully) and i'd like to display them on a seven segment led display.

I have the electronics side of things sorted out and even made a library to control my seven segment display (the main feature being a function that takes an array of 3 digits and displays them). I did all this assuming the easy part would be just inputing the status code but i can't figure out how to do that.

I've looked into it and thought i could use error handling but that would only work for status codes that correspond to an error and not the ones such as 200.

Any pointers ?

Comment: You want to use `@app.after_request` https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request

Comment: Thanls that looks promising. i'll look into it immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [@app.after_request](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.after_request)

I use this in many of my projects for posting log messages or metrics about calls made to my server. Combining `before_request` and `after_request` is also a common solution that many libraries use to implement features such as authentication in the flask framework.

Example:

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    print(f"Running from hello_world")
    return 'Hello, World!'


@app.after_request
def print_status_code(response):
    print(f"Status code is {response.status_code}")


app.run()
```

After making a GET call to `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` You will see:

```
Running from hello_world
Status code is 200
```

Comment: thanks for that i didnt know about the .status_code so i was busy parsing it out from the response itself haha, this will make life easier

Comment: @euan The docs are your friends! https://tedboy.github.io/flask/interface_api.response_object.html#flask.Response